# How to use some of ListView methods in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm used  **`RecyclerView`** for show and sort levels. because **`ListView`** has slowly speed i did not use **`listView`** and use **`RecyclerView`**. 
Therefore, i need some of the `ListView`methods, this methods has **SetScrollPosition** and **SetOnItemSelect** .

How can I make this method?

My RecyclerView Adapter codes :

```
public class levels_card_adapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder> {
private static String[] adapter_levels_number;

public levels_card_adapter(String[] adapter_levels_num_data) {
    adapter_levels_number = adapter_levels_num_data;



}

@Override
public levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.levels_recycler_layout, null);


    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setText(adapter_levels_number[position].toString());

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_version = adapter_levels_number[position];



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapter_levels_number.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView adapter_levels_text;

    public String adapter_levels_version;


    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        adapter_levels_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent question_page_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.tellfa.braingame.activities.question_Page.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(question_page_intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Activity Code :

```
public class play_Page extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView play_recycler_levels;
private RecyclerView.Adapter play_adapter_levels;
private TextView play_header_text;
private tellfa_textView play_thumbnail_levels_num, play_time_level_num;
private DiscreteSeekBar play_scroll_seekbar;
private com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle fb;
private Context context;
private ListView play_list_levels;

public static String[] levels_number = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play__page);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    ///////////// Font Style
    Typeface yekan_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yekan.ttf");

    play_header_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_play_text);
    play_header_text.setTypeface(yekan_font);
    /////////////

    play_thumbnail_levels_num = (tellfa_textView) findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);

    play_time_level_num = (tellfa_textView) findViewById(R.id.time_levels_num);

    ///////////// SeekBar
    play_scroll_seekbar = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.scroll_seekbar_play);



    ///////////// Recycler View
    play_recycler_levels = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.levels_recycler);

    play_recycler_levels.setHasFixedSize(true);

    play_recycler_levels.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    play_adapter_levels = new levels_card_adapter(levels_number);

    play_recycler_levels.setAdapter(play_adapter_levels);

    ////////////

    /*
    //////////// List
    com.tellfa.braingame.adapters.levels_list_adapter adapter=new com.tellfa.braingame.adapters.levels_list_adapter
            (this, levels_number);
    play_list_levels=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    play_list_levels.setAdapter(adapter);
    play_list_levels.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);
        ///////////
    */

    FrameLayout containerLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_id);
    HeaderAnimator animator = new HeaderAnimator(this);

    StikkyHeaderBuilder.stickTo(play_recycler_levels)
            .setHeader(R.id.header, containerLayout)
            .minHeightHeader(250)
            .animator(animator)
            .build();

    ///////////// Refresh
    final SwipeRefreshLayout play_refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh_play_layout);
    play_refresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh1, R.color.refresh2, R.color.refresh3, R.color.refresh4, R.color.refresh5);
    play_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            play_refresh.setRefreshing(true);

        }
    });

    ////


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder to obtain the same result as setOnItemSelect in ListView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setText(adapter_levels_number[position].toString());

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_version = adapter_levels_number[position];

    viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Output", "From inside recycler view");
        }
    });
}
```

Use scrollToPositionWithOffset() method if you are using LinearLayoutManger or StaggeredGridLayoutManager method that takes both the position and also the number of the pixels from the top value.

So for example, if you want item 1 in RecyclerView to be 50 pixels from the top

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(1, 50);
```

Comment: Thank you, dear friend, but i use this code in My Activity. edit up post and insert Activity code

Comment: Please help me, it very important for me